# Best way to set same value for a property of all objects in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, sequence

```
class Cell {
    var isSelected = true
}
var array: [Cell] = [Cell(), Cell(), Cell()]
```

Now I want to set isSelected property to 'false' for all objects in the array.

we can make it by a for loop, or can do with map

_ = array.map {$0.isSelected.true}

But I think there will be a better solution for this..

Comment: Are you looking for this: `array.forEach({ $0.isSelected = true })`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Larme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your class was a struct, you could do this during the array initialization:

```
var array = Array(repeating: Cell(isSelected: false), count: 3)
```

Technically you can do this with a class but first you'd need to add an appropriate `init` (that's easy), and second (big problem) you would end up with 3 references to a single instance of the class in your array which is probably not what you want.

If you really need a class and not a struct then using `forEach` is the proper way to visit each element of an array. `map` is not the correct solution.

```
array.forEach { $0.isSelected = false }
```

Comment: Thanks forEach is the soln. Btw I don’t want it with initialization.

Comment: FYI This is for resetting all models when select a new cell